# can I have a property in an object that is an array of multiple object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am converting my code from Javascript to Typescript my code below works in Javascript, but it has an error in Typescript

here is the code

```
const jsonData = {
        query: "keywords in here",
        page: {size: 10, current: 1},
        options: {
            all: [
                { datetimestart: {from: currentDateTimeInISOString}},
                { price: {from: 0, to: (freeEventsOnly ? 0.1 : 99999999999) }},
            ],
        },
};

if (meetSomeCondition) {
   jsonData.options.all.push({ city: domicile }); // <--- try to append another object to array
}
```

as you can see, I have an object called `jsonData`, and this object has a property called `options` which is an object that has property called `all` that is an array of multiple object

and then try to append another object to array, but I have this error

[image]

it seems I push an object that has different data type? how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literals cannot be different types.  Typescript infers a union type from all array elements in literal (you can see it in the error message). You can define `all` above `options` as `Record<string, any>[]`:

```
const all: Record<string, any>[] = [
                { datetimestart: {from: currentDateTimeInISOString}},
                { price: {from: 0, to: (freeEventsOnly ? 0.1 : 99999999999) }},
            ]
const jsonData = {
        query: "keywords in here",
        page: {size: 10, current: 1},
        options: {
            all,
        },
};
if (meetSomeCondition) {
   jsonData.options.all.push({ city: domicile }); // <--- try to append another object to array
}
```